# What JavaScript function will auto-submit a Qualtrics survey?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom-events, qualtrics

What JavaScript function will auto-submit a Qualtrics survey? I want to create a button in the header or footer of a Qualtrics survey that will automatically submit the survey whenever the user wants to quit. It seems like a pretty standard feature for survey software to have. **The question may not seem well researched but that's because there are NO Qualtrics resources out there on this.**

I found parts of the Qualtrics JS that might be relevant:

```
function pressSubmitButtonOnEnter(evt, id) {
    if (evt.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN) {
        Event.stop(evt);
        $(id).click();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This one as well:

```
function submitForm(formID) {
    var form = $(formID);
    if (form) {
        Event.fire(form, 'submit');
        if (form.onsubmit)
            form.onsubmit();
        if (form.submit)
            form.submit();
        return true;
    }
}
function submitFormJumpTo(formID, jumpTo) {
    $(formID).action = jumpTo;
    submitForm(formID);
}
```

This:

```
var SEonSubmit = {
    add : function (onSubmitFunction) {
        Event.observe('Page', 'submit', onSubmitFunction);
    }
};
var SEonClick = {
    add : function (onClickFunction) {
        Event.observe('Page', 'click', onClickFunction);
    }
};
```

Comment: You want a simple `<button type="submit">Quit</button>` with no JS at all?

Comment: It *has* to have JavaScript to trigger the survey submit mechanism (whatever that is).

Comment: How do you know that is "has to"? Maybe it just listens for native submit events? Where is the doc of that library (the minified source doesn't help)?

Comment: I've tried: <button type="submit">Quit</button> and it doesn't work. It just refreshes the page and an alert pops up saying that I can't use the back button. I only have access to the link to the minified js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Qualtrics, there is no way to do this. I submitted a request feature.

Answer (score 0):

This question is still relevant almost seven years later. I just spent a crazy amount of time trying to get this to work, it is exceptionally poorly documented.

The page with the intercept will have the QSI.API object.

```
QSI.API.load()
QSI.API.run()
```

Site Intercept JavaScript API

https://s.qualtrics.com/WRAPI/SiteIntercept/JavaScript/classes/API.html

Answer (score 0):

This is documented on an api support page from the Qualtrics website:
https://api.qualtrics.com/82bd4d5c331f1-qualtrics-java-script-question-api-class

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    /*Place your JavaScript here to run when the page loads*/

this.hideNextButton(); //Hides the next button
var that = this;
(function(){that.clickNextButton();}).delay(5); //displays the question for 5 seconds before moving to the next page

});
```